# Mock objects for real services

Tags: jakarta-ee, testing, mocking

I have many external 3rd party web-services that I need to access from my application and most of the times they are down or unavailable. I need to Mock the service return value say from an xml file that I have locally and send it back so that I can test the rest of the layers in my app i.e. presentation, delegate, etc. Is there a method to do this without writing an extra class for only testing purpose say a Mock object library that just gives some annotations that I can mark my production class-method and turn it on off based on say environment which will mock the specific method by pluging in to an sample-xml. for eg:

```
//MockthismethodFor(env).With(sampledata).returning(...)
@Mockthismethod("test","mytestvalues.xml",something)
public something returnsomthing(string str1){
//...production code
}
```

I checked EasyMock, Jmockit but not able to get much clue to achieve above.
Thanks for the pointers or any help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDI, you can use @Alternative to annotate your mock service implementation beans. Even better you can write your own @Mock stereotype and activate it in the environments real services are not available.  You can find the details here: http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/cdi-alternative-and-stereotypes/